# Android POSTing Json data

Tags: android, wcf, json

After much searching and trial-and-error, I found what I think is the *proper* way to post form data in json format to a Rest service (in this case, a WCF service).

My problem is that, although the json is formatted correctly, when I add it to .SetEntity, my json string becomes an array of numbers which throws a org.apache.http.client.HttpResponse.Exception

I am using a slightly altered version of Localtone's [POST JSON from Android using HttpClient](http://localtone.blogspot.com/2009/07/post-json-using-android-and-httpclient.html), it being in test mode, and all:

```
public String makeRequest() throws Exception {

        //set up the params here

        Map<Object,String> mp2=new HashMap<Object, String>();
        mp2.put("uName", "myUName");
        mp2.put("uPass", "myUPass");

        Map<String, Object> params=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("MyDC", mp2);  

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(getString(R.string.CONST_RestService) + "/json/Login");
        Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> iter = params.entrySet().iterator();

        JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();

        while(iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)iter.next();
        String key = (String)pairs.getKey();
        Map<?, ?> m = (Map)pairs.getValue();

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        Iterator iter2 = m.entrySet().iterator();
        while(iter2.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs2 = (Map.Entry)iter2.next();
        data.put((String)pairs2.getKey(), (String)pairs2.getValue());
        }
        holder.put(key, data);
        }

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString());
        httpost.setEntity(se);
        httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        response = httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);

        return response.toString();
        }
```

It all works well up to:

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString());
```

holder.toString() is correctly populated as

```
{"MyDC":{"uName":"myUName","uPass":"myUPass"}}
```

But once se is populated, se content becomes:

```
[123, 34, 77, 121, 68, 67, 34, 58, 123, 34, 117, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 34, 109, 121, 85, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 44, 34, 117, 80, 97, 115, 115, 34, 58, 34, 109, 121, 85, 80, 97, 115, 115, 34, 125, 125]
```

Which is then sent off as the `httpost.entity` and subsequently kills everything.

So, what is happening here? Why is the json string becoming an array of numbers?

Any Insight?

Thanks

Dave

Comment: have solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

se.getContent() will return a ByteArrayInputString. You would need to read the buffer and convert the stream into a string